# How to understand “isOnSyncQueue” function on AQS

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

When I read Java's source about AQS(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer),I got a doubt.

```
final boolean isOnSyncQueue(Node node) {
    if (node.waitStatus == Node.CONDITION || node.prev == null)
        return false;
    if (node.next != null) // If has successor, it must be on queue
        return true;
    /*
     * node.prev can be non-null, but not yet on queue because
     * the CAS to place it on queue can fail. So we have to
     * traverse from tail to make sure it actually made it.  It
     * will always be near the tail in calls to this method, and
     * unless the CAS failed (which is unlikely), it will be
     * there, so we hardly ever traverse much.
     */
    return findNodeFromTail(node);
}
```

The main doubt is the last comment.When a thread waiting on condition is signalled by other thread calling `signal()` method,its node has been enqueued into sync queue.

```
final boolean transferForSignal(Node node) {
    /*
     * If cannot change waitStatus, the node has been cancelled.
     */
    if (!node.compareAndSetWaitStatus(Node.CONDITION, 0))
        return false;

    /*
     * Splice onto queue and try to set waitStatus of predecessor to
     * indicate that thread is (probably) waiting. If cancelled or
     * attempt to set waitStatus fails, wake up to resync (in which
     * case the waitStatus can be transiently and harmlessly wrong).
     */
    Node p = enq(node);
    int ws = p.waitStatus;
    if (ws > 0 || !p.compareAndSetWaitStatus(ws, Node.SIGNAL))
        LockSupport.unpark(node.thread);
    return true;
}
```

If another thread not execute `enq(Node)` method completely, this node will try `compareAndSetTail(oldTail, node)` consistently until success.After it execute finish, this thread may be signalled.

I can image a circumstance that when `enq` method invoking, this thread is "surprise wake up", and execute `isOnSyncQueue` method.At this time its waitStatus not CONDITION and its prev is set in 'enq', so it can meet what the comment said.But, due to the node CAS fail, when invoke `findNodeFromTail` method it isn't in sync queue.`findNodeFromTail` make no sense.

When `enq` invoke successful, and prev node is cancelled, it will unpark this thread, but the thread has been surprise wake up, `isOnSyncQueue` method return false and the thread is blocked again. At this time it won't be signal again.

```
if (ws > 0 || !p.compareAndSetWaitStatus(ws, Node.SIGNAL))
    LockSupport.unpark(node.thread);
```

below is what I say(I'm not allowed to browse picture):

```
thread1: transferForSignal()  enq()
thread2: surprise wake up. execute isOnSyncQueue() and return fasle
thread1: enq() execute finish and prev is cancelled or CAS fail, 
         LockSupport.unpark(node.thread), this is make no sense.
thread2: LockSupport.park(this) and won't be signalled because 
         LockSupport.unpark(node.thread) has been invoked.
```

So, is me right? Or you can tell me why? Thank for you answer.